# How can I set two different paragraphs on the same line in G Docx using Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm working on a function that generates a Google Docx where it is listed, line by line, every character's name and its lyrics.
Every line is made up of two strings: character's name and lyrics.
Well, I get my goal using `insertTable` and formatting it, getting every line as a two column table.

```js
var table = body.insertTable(0, [[pers, text]]);
    var styles = {};
    styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = '#ffffff';
    styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
    styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
    table.setAttributes(styles);
```

This is the result:

[image: docx script]

The issue arises because now I need to manipulate this file and I'm struggling to work with so many tables!
The question is: is there a way to get the same result without using tables? I tried `body.appendParagraph()` but I can't figure out how to format the paragraph the same as in the above image.

Can you please help me? ..and.. I do apologize for my bad english!!

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? Could you provide some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can format a paragraph and get the same look:

[image]

You have to insert a `tab` symbol after a personage name and set so called 'hanging indentation' for the paragraph.

The code could be something like this:

```
function setIndents() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var indent = 100;
  doc.getBody().getParagraphs().forEach(p => p.setIndentStart(indent));
}
```

It sets the 'hanging indentation' (100 pt) for all existed paragraphs in current document.